# fast-csv returns undefined data when headers is true

Tags: node.js, csv, express, mongoose

I'm having a small problem with fast-csv. And that problem is that when I set headers to true, I get "undefined" data (and only empty data gets pushed to the database).

```
const db = require("../models");
const fs = require("fs");
const csv = require("fast-csv");
const csvfile = "./public/csv/vendor_example.csv";
const stream = fs.createReadStream(csvfile);

router.get("/import_data", (req, res, next) => {
  // csv.fromStream(stream, { headers: true });
  var csvStream = csv(stream, { headers: true })
    .on("data", function(data) {
      // products.push(data);
      var imported_data = new db.Products({
        // date: new Date(),
        column1: data[0]
      });

      imported_data.save(error => {
        console.log(skus_data);
        if (error) {
          throw error;
        }
      });
    })
    .on("end", function() {
      console.log("ended");
    });

  stream.pipe(csvStream);

  // res.json({ success: "Data Imported", status: 200 });
  res.json({
    success: "Data imported with no errors",
    status: 200
  });
});
```

However, when I remove "stream, { headers: true }", it does work, but the headers get pushed to the database.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
  var imported_data = new db.Products({
    // date: new Date(),
    column1: data[0]
  });
```

Instead of data[0], I needed to specify the name of the header, e.x:

column1: data.names